# Retrieving data from the table using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to retrieve all the information about each department from the DEPARTMENT table and display the information on the screen.

```
Column name      Data type     Constraints

DEPARTMENT_ID    NUMBER(5)     PK

DEPARTMENT_NAME  VARCHAR2(25)  NOT NULL

LOCATION_ID      VARCHAR2(15)

Sample Output:

Department Details are :
1000, ADMIN, HQ-101

1010, DEVELOPMENT, CBE-103

1020, TESTING, CHN-102
```

I have a code which is as follows-

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
v_dno department.department_id%type;
v_dname department.department_name%type;
v_loc department.location_id%type;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Department Details are :');
loop
dbms_output.put_line(v_dno || ', ' || v_dname || ', ' || v_loc);
end loop;
commit;
end;
/
```

But this isn't producing any output, please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once it is saved you need a **Select** to get data out of the database. I suggest you do some research on the [Select](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) and the pl/sql [Select Into](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345) statements and then perhaps spend some time studying the [Oracle 2 Day Developers Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tdddg/index.html).

Comment: That's today's homework, apparently. Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451246/retrieving-the-data-from-the-table-using-the-pl-sql

Answer (score 1):

IN SQL if you want to retrieve data from a table, view, etc. You need to use the **SELECT** statement. In your anonymous block you aren't using the select, and you're looping the empty variables. So you need to add the select in your code like this (*You can do it with a declared cursor too, but in this case i made it in line on the FOR*):

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Department Details are :');
for c in (select department_id, department_name, location_id from department) loop
  dbms_output.put_line(c.department_id|| ', ' || c.department_name|| ', ' || 
  c.location_id);
end loop;
commit;
end;
```

Since you are using a **cursor**, there is no need to declare and use variables at all.