# Retrieving the data from the table using the PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to retrieve all the information about each department from the DEPARTMENT table and display the information on the screen.

```
Column name      Data type     Constraints

DEPARTMENT_ID    NUMBER(5)     PK

DEPARTMENT_NAME  VARCHAR2(25)  NOT NULL

LOCATION_ID      VARCHAR2(15)

Sample Output:

Department Details are :
1000, ADMIN, HQ-101

1010, DEVELOPMENT, CBE-103

1020, TESTING, CHN-102
```

I have a code which is as follows-

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
v_dno department.department_id%type;
v_dname department.department_name%type;
v_loc department.location_id%type;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Department Details are :');
loop
dbms_output.put_line(v_dno || ', ' || v_dname || ', ' || v_loc);
end loop;
commit;
end;
/
```

But this isn't producing any output, please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to assign values to your variables. I suggest that you read the _PL/SQL Language Reference_ for the version of Oracle database that you are using. It is part of the Oracle documentation and is available online.

Comment: Have a look at [`select into`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html).

Comment: _EXACTLY_ the same as asked by @Phaniraj N V, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449446/retrieving-data-from-the-table-using-pl-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a simple way to do that is to use a loop. But, you're looping through *nothing* (never fetch anything into those variables) and never exit the loop. Besides, what exactly are you committing?

Here's how you might have done it (based on Scott's `DEPT` table which is similar to yours):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select deptno, dname, loc from dept) loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.deptno ||' '|| cur_r.dname ||' '|| cur_r.loc);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
10 ACCOUNTING NEW YORK
20 RESEARCH DALLAS
30 SALES CHICAGO
40 OPERATIONS BOSTON

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```